# How fast can I vote to avoid the system thinkig that I'm a bot?

Tags: discussion, voting

Badge hunting, does it go against the rules of the website?

if it doesn't, how fast can I vote questions and answer to get the badges?
the limit is 40 votes per day, can I just take a few minutes to get all the votes in?

Comment: *Fast voting ?* Why would you need vote count badges as quick as possible ? read it first, before you vote. And there are only a few vote count badges.. there are some 200 other badges here, these do not involve voting at all. Answers (good) and questions (good), upvoted comments and proposals to edit things bring many more badges.. and points.. eg I'm a point hunter, rather than a badge hunter.

Comment: If all people voted only and only to get badges, then the point of voting would make no sense as a whole to anyone, and so will the voting and voted badges. Please take more than a few minutes to decide if all 40 posts are worth an upvote :).

Answer (score 9):

Votes shall be given to the post, not to the user behind it. Targeted voting is forbidden and punished. That is to say, if you give 40 votes to the same user, that will rise more than an eyebrow.

Also please take time to evaluate what you are voting. Upvoting a clearly poor post does no good to the community.

Comment: Good to know, so are there other negative sides to voting a lot of questions/answers every day? other than potentially raising low quality content to the top ?

Comment: @RPGlife worst case scenario is being (manually) suspended from using the site.

Comment: @Pureferret so is it allowed or not?

Comment: @RPGlife Pro tip. If there isn't a policy about something, don't conduct yourself in a way that will result in a policy being created.

Comment: @sphennings well ,I asked, will read everything that I vote then.

Comment: Curious: how would "they" know if someone is only voting for one or two other users?

Comment: @elemtilas probably there's a regular time set check that every so often see's your vote order automatically and if anything suspicious is happening, a notice arrives to the moderators. Just my guess, other than that, probably moderators can simply see your vote order from your profile.

Answer (score 5):

> Badge hunting, does it go against the rules of the website?

No. Badges exist to encourage you towards good user behaviour.

> Badges have been around since the beginning of Stack Overflow. **They are our way of recognizing our contributors for engaging with the community in meaningful ways**. ([from the SO blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/12/stack-overflow-badges-explained/)).

> if it  doesn't, how fast can I vote questions and answer to get the badges? the limit is 40 votes per day, can I just take a few minutes to get all the votes in?

It's not about how fast. I've once used up all my votes in less than a handful of minutes, because I saw a question with many answers and all answers were good.

Voting a lot is not a problem. Voting a lot on just some specific person may raise an eyebrow, as Dutch said. But consider two things:

1. The bot catching algorithm is never divulged, for security reasons.
2. There are a handful of people in this site who always give good answers and I am consistently upvoting them. Since there is no favoritism and I upvote a lot of people, the algorithm has never had a problem with me. As long as you're being honest, you've got nothing to fear.

Comment: I'd like to voice my appreciation for and underscore the following remark: `Badges exist to encourage you towards good user behaviour.` Badge hunting is good. Badge farming kinda suggests someone doesn't understand why the badges exist.